# Using macros to generalise code for function calls

Tags: c, embedded, c-preprocessor, compile-time

I'm writing C code which requires me to use multiple function calls of the same definition which differ only by single characters. Is there a way I can make a macro function which takes say a number and can insert these calls into my code for me where I call the macro given I know the numbers at compile time:

i.e.

```
#define call_pin_macro(X)
    enable_pin#X();
    do_thing_pin#X();
    do_other_thing_pin#X();
            .
            .
void pin_function(void){
    call_pin_macro(1);
    call_pin_macro(2);
    call_pin_macro(3);
}
```

Instead of:

```
void pin_function(void){
     enable_pin1();
     do_thing_pin1();
     do_other_thing_pin1();
     enable_pin2();
     do_thing_pin2();
     do_other_thing_pin2();
     enable_pin3();
     do_thing_pin3();
     do_other_thing_pin3();
```

}

As a note I have looked at stringification (Hence the included #X's) in gcc however I cannot get the above code to compile which I get an error "error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter". And it thus it seems this isn't exactly the functionality I am after. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note:  a macro that is written on multiple lines requires the '\' to concatenate the lines. So #define call_pin_macro(X)\enable_pin#X();\...

Answer (score 2):

In gcc you can do it like this:

```
#define call_pin_macro(X)   \
    enable_pin##X();           \
    do_thing_pin##X();         \
    do_other_thing_pin##X();
```

The double hash is the [macro concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation) operator. You don't want to use stringify because that will put quotes around it.

The backslashes allow you to continue the macro over several lines.

Comment: Does a double ## have a specific (i.e. unique) meaning to the preprocessor similar to a single # symbol or is there some other coding intuition at use here by making use of two # symbols consecutively.

Comment: it has it's own meaning: concatenation